# Alternatives to JasperReports and BIRT

Tags: java, reporting

I'm looking for a Java reporting engine that:

- does not force you to use a designer to define report templates (and hence allows generation of reports by means of API),
- is not JasperReports nor BIRT,
- is open source,
- is free (as in both freedom and free beer),
- is decent in your opinion.

It's a hard question, I know. I could not find anything satisfactory on Google nor here in Stack Overflow but I still hope that someone might know some hidden treasure somewhere.

Comment: What is your ultimate goal? JR doesn't require you to use a designer; what are your other objections? Would you be happier just using iText?

Comment: Why using JR or Birt not applicable in your case? There aren't that many reporting libraries for Java anyways.

Comment: Jasper doesnt force you to use their designer you can freely create the jrxml yourself which defines the report.  I'm also struggling with why/how you would construct the report layout via an API unless you were creating more or less the 'designer' yourself.  Can you elaborate a little on what your development goal is in this?

Comment: http://java-source.net/open-source/charting-and-reporting

Comment: First of all, thanks for your replies. Let me make it clear that I did NOT say that JR and BIRT force you to use a designer and I'm NOT saying they are not applicable to my case. The decision of doing everything via API is a personal choice of mine. I would like to ask you guys to focus on an answer to the question. Would love to hear your personal experiences with reporting libraries other than JR and BIRT that of course match the conditions stated above.

Comment: For an API like approach you can use XSL-FO. Personally I'd rather go to a Meryl Streep movie marathon than use XSL-FO (it's write once in my opinion) but it does fit your criteria of free and an API.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are not a lot of open-source enterprise reporting tools (reporting tools in the spirit of crystal reports).  The two biggest are BIRT and JasperReport.  JFreeReport (seems to be dead) and DataVision (no experience) are the only two "other" open-source products that even come close.

The bulk of near-reporting products center around graph generation, or document generation.  While the latter might seem like it is "reporting", some of the efforts fail to consider a range of generated documents (LaTEX only, or similar).

Part of the problem is that the type of product you are considering has always provided a drag-and-drop report authoring tool because this kind of reporting grew into it's own by emulating word processing with templates.  This leads to your other requirement, a programmatic API.

In the end, your API is going to generate the report template, which will then get passed to the engine that merges the report with it's data, formats it, and then renders it.  As such, a tool like JasperReports (where the jrxml template is relatively well defined) doesn't sound too bad; because, you can just use Java to build a DOM tree (which is the report template) and then pass that into the engine (perhaps you will have to serialize it to XML first, but it could be worse).

Except that you dismiss out-of-hand JasperReports (and the other biggest reporting platform, BIRT) for reasons unknown.  While there may be excellent reasons not to use certain available products (I can't user JaserReports myself due to some excellent reasons), if too many of the products are deemed unusable, you run out of viable permitted products.

The only holdout is DataVision, and it generates either LaTeX or Docbook.  You can get most of the "standard" expected formats with a Docbook build chain, but it greatly complicates your report rendering pipeline, and you'll have to get a strong understanding of Docbook's XSLT styling to get any kind of decent style (a typical "beauty" requirement for many corporate reports).

Good Luck, and I hope this information is of some benefit.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I will stick with JasperReports, it's not exactly what I was looking for but it's a very good engine.

Answer (score 0):

You should try out Helical Insight. It is an Open Source tool with a lot of APIs. There is no restriction for creating report templates. In fact, you can add any JS chart to the engine as per your requirement.
You can check out the community edition on Github. It is free.
You can also try out the enterprise edition with a 30 day free trial. The pricing is very affordable compared to all other tools.

Comment: For the lazy, here is [the github site](https://github.com/helicalinsight/helicalinsight) and [the company page](https://www.helicalinsight.com/).  Currently, the last commit on github other than changes to the pom.xml and the docs was 2019-10-16.